# Plesk's default web server page is displayed after adding a new Virtual Host in Wamp

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I added a new VirtualHost named `khabgahyar.test` via wampServer. and I am sure that all things are true.

But whenever I open that host in Chrome or other browsers, it shows a `Web Server's Default Page` Plesk.

[image]

I refreshed the page many times and cleared the browser cache but the problem continues.

really I do not understand the problem and Why a Plesk Page is shown!

Comment: If you have Plesk you must use that to create websites and set up hosting.

Comment: No, I have not any Plesk installation on my System and it is I am feeling surprised.

Comment: In that case the DNS records of your domain do not point to your web server, because the image in your question indicates that the server does use Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is with using a v2Ray VPN Connection. When I disabled it, the problem was solved.

Another way is to create a VirtualHost only with IP Address in Wamp Server